# Laravel + Polymer

Tags: laravel, polymer

I am trying to integrate Polymer into my Laravel app. So I created this custom web component and when I put that into my Laravel view, **I get to see only blank screen**. I'm using Laravel's built in web server in-case you think it can be the issue of HTML imports.

proto-element.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="proto-element" noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>Proto element</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

hello.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function supportsImports() {
          return 'import' in document.createElement('link');
        }

        if (supportsImports()) {
          // Good to go!
        } else {
          // Use other libraries/require systems to load files.
        }
    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/proto-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <proto-element></proto-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you using? 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 0.5 syntax instead of 1.0 syntax in the declaration of your custom element. Here's how you would do it in 1.0.

```
<dom-module id="proto-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Proto element</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "proto-element"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Maria